# Difference between two XMLTYPE data types

Tags: oracle, datatypes

In Oracle Database, there are two XML-related data types, `SYS.XMLTYPE` and `PUBLIC.XMLTYPE`.
What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

That's simple.

Check the object type of the "public" object

```
select object_type
from all_objects
where owner = 'PUBLIC'
and object_name = 'XMLTYPE';
```

the above returns

```
OBJECT_TYPE
-----------
SYNONYM
```

So we have to look into `all_synonyms`:

```
select owner, synonym_name, table_owner, table_name
from all_synonyms
where synonym_name = 'XMLTYPE';
```

returns:

```
OWNER  | SYNONYM_NAME | TABLE_OWNER | TABLE_NAME
-------+--------------+-------------+-----------
PUBLIC | XMLTYPE      | SYS         | XMLTYPE
```